# cp with matched pattern of parent directories

Tags: linux, find, cp

copy directory with a matched pattern of parent directories

```
cp 
dir/group1/sub01/./././DCM
dir/group2/sub01/././DCM
to 
dir/Base/group1/sub01/Time1/
dir/Base/group2/sub01/Time1/
with matched group name and sub name
output: 
dir/Base/group1/sub01/Time1/DCM
dir/Base/group2/sub01/Time1/DCM
```

I was thinking maybe

```
find * -type d -name "DCM" -execdir bash -c 'old="$1"; new="$(cd ../../..; basename --"$PWD")/$(cd ../..; basename --"$PWD")"; cp -r "$old" "dir/Base/$new"' - {} \;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing long complex lines I will offer you to do it with `awk`:

```
new_dir=$(echo "$dir" | awk -F\/ '{print "dir/Base/"$2"/"$3"/Time1/"}')
```

and the script may become:

```
while read dir
do
  new_dir=$(echo "$dir" | awk -F\/ '{print "dir/Base/"$2"/"$3"/Time1/"}')
  cp -fdR "$dir" "$new_dir"
done <(find . -type d -name DCM)
```

Comment: neat and clear, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Using `zsh`:

```bsh
autoload -U zmv
zmv -v -C -o -R -- 'dir/(group<->)/(sub<->)/**/DCM' 'dir/Base/$1/$2/Time1/'
```

The `zmv` command above takes an extended globbing pattern and a destination pathname.  The globbing pattern may contain "capture groups" (parenthesized expressions) that you may refer to with `$1`, `$2`, etc. in the destination pathname.  The command above captures the names of the `group` and `sub` subdirectories (where `<->` matches any number).

The options used here are `-n` for a "dry-run" (don't actually carry out any copying; remove this when certain that it works), `-v` for "verbose" operation, and `-C` to do copying rather than moving. We use `-o -R` to pass `-R` to `cp`.

Testing:

```bsh
$ tree
.
`-- dir
    |-- Base
    |   |-- group1
    |   |   `-- sub01
    |   |       `-- Time1
    |   `-- group2
    |       `-- sub01
    |           `-- Time1
    |-- group1
    |   `-- sub01
    |       `-- a
    |           `-- b
    |               `-- c
    |                   `-- DCM
    `-- group2
        `-- sub01
            `-- a
                `-- b
                    `-- DCM
```

```bsh
$ zmv -v -C -o -R -- 'dir/(group<->)/(sub<->)/**/DCM' 'dir/Base/$1/$2/Time1/'
cp -R -- dir/group1/sub01/a/b/c/DCM dir/Base/group1/sub01/Time1/
cp -R -- dir/group2/sub01/a/b/DCM dir/Base/group2/sub01/Time1/
```

```bsh
$ tree
.
`-- dir
    |-- Base
    |   |-- group1
    |   |   `-- sub01
    |   |       `-- Time1
    |   |           `-- DCM
    |   `-- group2
    |       `-- sub01
    |           `-- Time1
    |               `-- DCM
    |-- group1
    |   `-- sub01
    |       `-- a
    |           `-- b
    |               `-- c
    |                   `-- DCM
    `-- group2
        `-- sub01
            `-- a
                `-- b
                    `-- DCM
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might work:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e -o pipefail


find . -type d -name DCM | while read dir; do
  new_dir_suffix=`echo "$dir" | sed 's/^.*group/group/' | sed 's|\(sub[0-9]*\).*DCM|\1/Time1|'`
  cp -fdR "$dir" dir/base/"$new_dir_suffix"
done
```

Setting variables in `bash -c` commands won't work because the variables only exist  within the context of those Bash invocations. There's no way to set environment variables from `find`.

Comment: You can pass variables into a `bash -c` script. `... -exec bash -c 'some looping code' bash {} +`. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697